# What is this function doing for Game Of Life project

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Game of Life project.  I was advised to make my own iterative function so I can use it whenever I need to iterate.  Here is my current code for this section:

```
var onCellClick = function (event) {

    // how to set the style of the cell when it's clicked
    if(this.className === "dead") {
      this.className = "alive";
    } else {
      this.className = "dead";
    }
  };

  //applies the onclick listener to the entire board.
  this.iterateCells(function(cell, x, y) {
    cell.onclick = onCellClick;
  });

  GameOfLife.prototype.iterateCells = function(iterator) {
  for(var y=0; y < this.height; y++) {
    for(var x=0; x < this.width; x++) {
      var currentCell = document.getElementById(x+"-"+y);
      iterator(currentCell, x, y);
    }
  }
};
```

What I am doing is making the 'onCellClick' function active for every cell in my 20/20 grid.

I am unsure of

a) in the iterate cell function, what is the iterator being passed in as a parameter? What is it's value? This is the biggest part I am confused on.

b) when this.iterateCells(function(cell,x,y) what is the function actually doing that's being passed as the iterator parameter?

Here is a link to the project incase you need to see more of what is going on http://jsfiddle.net/8Tut6/3/

Comment: a) See ["Event object references"](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript). b) Is unclear - cell is the cell object, x and y are where it's located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript, which means you can store them in variables and pass them as parameters. For example:

```
// this function executes a function that is passed as a parameter
function execute(func)
{
    func();
}

function hello()
{
    alert("Hello, World!");
}

execute(hello);
execute(function () { alert("Hello again!"); });
```

This code alerts "Hello, World!" and then "Hello again!".

Specifically to answer your question:

a) `iterator` is `function(cell, x, y) { cell.onclick = onCellClick; }`

b) The function is being called multiple times by `iterateCells`.